# How do I make sure all GUI input variables can be accessed by certain classes and function calls?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

When I provide an address /and or location to the entry bar and I press the "Get forecast" button the script fails at line 22. I think the error is raised  because the str(address.get()) cant find the address variable, probably because it doesn't technically exist during that point of run time (I'm not able to log the error due to the structure of that function).

**My question is; How do I make sure that my "get_hourly_forecast" function is able to access the address entry variable?**

I have tried instantiating the address variable in various locations, e.g in the MainWeatherHub class, as well as in the MyWeatherApp class and then passing it as an argument to the MainWeatherHub in line 79, neither variation has worked. The current code shows the former variation.

```
import urllib, json, requests
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def get_hourly_forecast(*args):

        #@ params *args:
        #A location argument

        #Returns:
        #   A list of temps in Farenheit for the next 156 hours

    API_KEY = 'removing my API key for security purposes'
    try:
        print('here') # The code makes it to here
        curr_address = str(address.get()) # Code seems to fail here (not sure how to have the error print)
        print('here')
        geocode_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={}&key={}".format(cur_address, API_KEY)
        response = requests.get(geocode_url)
        response_dict = response.json()['results']
        location = response_dict[0]['geometry']['location']
        lat = location['lat']
        lng = location['lng']

        local_url_request = 'https://api.weather.gov/points/lat={}lng={}'.format(lat, lng)
        response_one = requests.get(local_url_request)
        json_dict_one = response_one.json()
        local_props = json_dict_one['properties']
        local_forecast_request = local_props['forecastHourly']

        resposne_two = requests.get(local_forecast_request)
        json_dict_two = resposne_two.json()
        local_forecast_properites = json_dict_two['properties']
        hourly_updates = local_forecast_properites['periods']

        out = []

        for i in hourly_updates:
            for key, value in i.items():
                if key == "temperature":
                    out.append(value)

        current_weather.set(out[0])

    except:
        print("Not working.")


#############################################################


class MyWeatherApp:

    """

    MyWeatherApp is the primary Frame for this GUI application

    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(MyWeatherApp, self).__init__()
        self.master = master

        # Create the main window Frame
        master_style = ttk.Style()
        master_style.configure('Master.TFrame')
        self.master.title("My Weather")
        self.master.geometry("500x500")
        MWA = ttk.Frame(self.master, style='Master.TFrame')
        MWA.place(relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)

        # Run other widgets within this class
        MainWeatherHub(MWA)


#############################################################


class MainWeatherHub(MyWeatherApp):

    """

    The MainWeatherHub (MWH) is the top panel of the app

    """

    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        super(MyWeatherApp, self).__init__()
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow

        # Create a Frame for the MainWeatherHub
        MWH_style = ttk.Style()
        MWH_style.configure('MWH.TFrame')
        MWH = ttk.Frame(self.mainwindow, style='MWH.TFrame', relief='sunken')
        MWH.place(relheight=0.33, relwidth=0.95, relx=0.025, rely=0.025)

        # Create an entry widget to take a location
        # and store that as a loction variable.
        address = StringVar()
        loc_entry = ttk.Entry(MWH, textvariable=address)
        loc_entry.place(relheight=0.30, relwidth=.95, relx=0.025, rely=0.05)

        # Get weather button finds weather for the users location
        current_weather = StringVar()
        get_weather_button = ttk.Button(loc_entry, text="Get Forecast", command=get_hourly_forecast)
        get_weather_button.place(relheight=0.85,relwidth=0.2, relx=0.79, rely=0.075)

        #Display weather in the Message widget
        weath_display = Message(MWH, textvariable=current_weather)
        weath_display.place(relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.55, relx=0.025, rely=0.375)

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyWeatherApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If this script works properly, it should return the current temperature in degrees Fahrenheit of the location that was provided in the entry bar.

Comment: This code has a highly unusual structure. If `MainWeatherHub` is a subclass of `MainWeatherApp`, you typically won't create an instance of `MainWeatherHub` inside `MainWeatherApp`. This complicates a proper solution to what you are asking. Are you willing to accept advice about how to avoid this complication?

Comment: Bryan, thank you very much for the assessment. I was worried that my structure was going to cause complications and become unsustainable. I'm relatively new to python, and even newer to building GUI's so I would love a critique of the structure and I will take any and all suggestions.

Comment: assign to button method which runs `get_hourly_forecast` with parameter `address.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send it as parameter

```
def get_hourly_forecast(cur_address):
    geocode_url = "...".format(cur_address, API_KEY)
```

And then assing to button function which runs `get_hourly_forecast` with string

```
class MainWeatherHub(MyWeatherApp):

    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        self.address = StringVar() # use self.
        ttk.Button(loc_entry, text="Get Forecast", command=run_it)   

    def run_it(self):
        get_hourly_forecast(self.address.get())
```

or using `lambda`

```
class MainWeatherHub(MyWeatherApp):

    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        ttk.Button(loc_entry, text="Get Forecast", command=lambda:get_hourly_forecast(address.get()))
```

---

**EDIT:**

I see you use `current_weather` (`StringVar` from `MainWeatherHub`) in `get_hourly_forecast` to set value `current_weather.set(out[0])`.

You could send current_weather to `get_hourly_forecast` as parameter

```
def get_hourly_forecast(cur_address, current_weather):
    geocode_url = "...".format(cur_address, API_KEY)

    current_weather.set(out[0])
```

and

```
class MainWeatherHub(MyWeatherApp):

    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        self.address = StringVar() # use self.
        self.current_weather = StringVar() # use self.
        ttk.Button(loc_entry, text="Get Forecast", command=run_it)   

    def run_it(self):
        get_hourly_forecast(self.address.get(), self.current_weather)
```

but it could be better to return value from `get_hourly_forecast`

```
def get_hourly_forecast(cur_address):
    geocode_url = "...".format(cur_address, API_KEY)

    return out[0]
```

and get it in `run_it`

```
    def run_it(self):
        result = get_hourly_forecast(self.address.get())
        if result is not None:
            self.current_weather.set(result)
```

This way `get_hourly_forecast` doesn't work with `StringVar` and you can use it in other program which doesn't use `StringVar`.

Comment: Thanks, Furas. Very straightforward solution.

Comment: now I see you use also `current_weather` inside `get_hourly_forecast` - so you should send it also as parameter `get_hourly_forecast(cur_address, current_weather):` Or `get_hourly_forecast()` should use `return out[0]` and `run_it()` should get it and put in `current_weather`.

Comment: I added example with `current_weather`

Comment: You found my next issue, lol. Thank you for being so thorough.